# Obtaining assert info from a truncated embedded linux (arm) core dump

Tags: embedded-linux, coredump

I have insufficent flash space to store a full linux core dump on an OMAPL168-based portable device, but would particularly like to obtain basic assert params (filename, line number, assert test). This info is contained in the full core dump, but appears to be located somewhere near the end of the 5Meg dump. I would like to have the ability to specify the desired content of a reduced-size coredump, since the ulimit -c x simply results in giving you the first xK of the binary. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Although this might be a usage question on a full-size system, in an embedded context it's likely a programmer debugging issue, where knowledge of system settings may or may not contribute to an efficient solution.  Neither down nor close votes seem particularly deserved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip the core dump entirely, and do intentional logging either to a file, or to a remote serial/network monitor?

Or mount a network filesystem, usb stick or even an spi-mode SD card and set up the core dump to go there.